# Widgets not showing up in maximized PyQt5 Window

Tags: python, pyqt5

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.showMaximized()
    self.setWindowTitle("MyCoolBrowser")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me", self)
    self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 50)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

My pushbutton is not shown in the window when I run my code. But, When I delete the line "self.showMaximized()", then the pushbutton is shown. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widgets created just as children (without being added to a layout) are not automatically shown *after* their parent has already been shown.

The simple solution is to move `showMaximized()` *after* the button is created, as it's always good practice to call any `show()` related function *after* all objects are created.

The **good** answer is to correctly set a *central widget* (which is what a QMainWindow shows as its main content) and possibly use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) if more widgets are going to be shown, and avoid any attempt to use fixed geometries (size and position) which is considered a bad practice (use spacers or stretchs if needed):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("MyCoolBrowser")
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.editor)

        # add a "stretch" at the bottom of the layout in order to 
        # "push" everything on top
        layout.addStretch()

        self.showMaximized()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```